# cleos data getting inserted and deleted but table shows empty record

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, accounts, table, get-table

I have written one smart contract for insert, update and delete data. The smart contract is compiled and deployed to the two accounts. I insert data using calling the action *upsert*, this transaction was successful. Same I delete data using action *erase*, this transaction also gets success. but when I try to get data using

> cleos get table varshaccount member people

and

> cleos get table memberacc member people

it returns empty. Below is my code:

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/print.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace eosio;
using std::string;

class [[eosio::contract("member")]] member : public eosio::contract {

        public:

        using contract::contract;

        member(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds):contract(receiver, code, ds) {}

        [[eosio::action]]
                void upsert(name user, std::string first_name, std::string last_name, std::string contact, std::string address) {
                        require_auth( user );
                        member_index addresses( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value );
                        auto iterator = addresses.find(user.value);
                        if( iterator == addresses.end() )
                        {
                                //user is not in table so add new record
                                addresses.emplace(user, [&]( auto& row ) {
                                                row.key = user;
                                                row.first_name = first_name;
                                                row.last_name = last_name;
                                                row.contact = contact;
                                                row.address = address;
                                                });
                        }
                        else {
                                //user is in table so modify
                                addresses.modify(iterator, user, [&]( auto& row ) {
                                                row.key = user;
                                                row.first_name = first_name;
                                                row.last_name = last_name;
                                                row.contact = contact;
                                                row.address = address;
                                                });
                        }
                }
        [[eosio::action]]
                void erase(name user) {
                        require_auth(user);
                        member_index addresses( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value);
                        auto iterator = addresses.find(user.value);
                        check(iterator != addresses.end(), "Record does not exist");
                        addresses.erase(iterator);
                }

        private:

                struct [[eosio::table]] memberinfo
                {
                        name key;
                        std::string first_name;
                        std::string last_name;
                        std::string contact;
                        std::string address;
                        uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value;}
                };
                typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, memberinfo> member_index;

};
```

Here is my abi:

```
{
    "____comment": "This file was generated with eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT ",
    "version": "eosio::abi/1.1",
    "types": [],
    "structs": [
        {
            "name": "erase",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "user",
                    "type": "name"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "memberinfo",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "key",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "first_name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "contact",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
         {
            "name": "upsert",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "user",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "first_name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "contact",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "name": "erase",
            "type": "erase",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "upsert",
            "type": "upsert",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        }
    ],
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "people",
            "type": "memberinfo",
            "index_type": "i64",
            "key_names": [],
            "key_types": []
        }
    ],
    "ricardian_clauses": [],
    "variants": []
}
```

Note: The account **varshaccount** is also used to deploy another smart contract before. So, I created new account that is **memberacc**, but facing same issue.

Comment: I created a new account with the same name of the contract. It's working fine for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set get_first_receiver() as the scope of member_index. If this action is not sent by other contract, first_receiver will be the account where the contract is deployed.

```
[[eosio::action]]
void upsert(name user, std::string first_name, std::string last_name, std::string contact, std::string address) {
  require_auth( user );
  // 2nd argument here is the scope of member_index
  member_index addresses( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value );
```

`cleos get table` command accepts three fields, code, scope and table, so you should run `cleos get table varshaccount varshaccount people`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!